# How can i send an XML file as an object to some other function

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I needed to read(load) one xml file, and send the same file as an object to other function. Here the problem I am facing is, while loading the file, it is converted to XML Object. Now we can get the details of the file by accessing the InnerXML property, where it got converted to String.

How can I get this String object get assigned to an normal Object whose properties are internally similar to this xml?

See the sample:

```
SearchResponse Response = new SearchResponse(); 
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load(@"C:\Search_Response.xml"); 
Object response = new Object(); 
response = doc.InnerXml; 
Response = (SearchResponse)response; 
return Response;
```

Please help me out!

Comment: Can you post an example of what `SearchResponse` and `Response` look like?  I'm thinking LINQ to XML would work nicely for you in this case.

Comment: Hi, SearchResponse is having a complex structure with multiple inner objects. But one thing i can tell is like its objects are perfect copy of the XML read.

Comment: Is the `SearchResponse` you're using the one from `System.DirectoryServicesProtocols`?  If so, even with a complex structure you can do this fairly easily with LINQ to XML. Could you post an example of the XML?

Comment: The idea I'm working off on this is that rather than converting the XML to an Object and then explicitly casting the Object to a SearchResponse, you could load the XML and via LINQ to XML create a new instance of the SearchResponse class.  I think that would be more efficient.

Comment: No SearchResponse is an internal DLL that we have created. The structure of xml resembles like   <Search><searchParty></searchParty> <Search>. Inside this SearchParty also multiple subtabs comes whitch is included as corresponding subclasses of this SearchResponse.

Comment: Ah..ok.  Regardless, I think my point still stands.  You know the properties and collections of the object, you know the format of the XML - the translation is pretty straight forward.

Comment: The Object structure is too complex, to do translation in Object Level...That's why tried to find an alternate way...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by `Serialization`.

Comment: Could you please include a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

use `Microsoft.Http.HttpClient`. This will give you to convert Xml to Object Very easily.

Eg:

```
    SearchResponse Response = new SearchResponse(); 
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var httpResponseMessage = client.Get(uri);
    Response =   httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsXmlSerializable<SearchResponse >();
```